# Nokia / HERE maps goes back to level 0 zoom after map.zoomTo

Tags: javascript, here-api

My javascript code loops through some user data and adds each one as a marker to a container. It then adds that container to a nokia map and uses the Display zoomTo to zoom to the bounding box of the container holding all the markers.
However, right after that happens, the map just zooms itself all the way back out. The zoomTo call is the very last of my code that executes so it seems like something weird is going on.

```
    this.finishMapping = function () {
        map.objects.add(multiMapContainer);

        var markerHopefully = multiMapContainer.objects.get(0);

        $.ajax({
            dataType: "jsonp",
            url: "https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id=WgevZ2m4AF8WHx1TY6GS&app_code=G11AO2dbvCRTdCjfTf-mUw&waypoint0=geo!" + markerHopefully.coordinate.latitude + "," + markerHopefully.coordinate.longitude + "&waypoint1=geo!" + markerHopefully.coordinate.latitude + "," + markerHopefully.coordinate.longitude + "&mode=fastest;car;",
            success: function (data) {
                onRouteCalculated(data)
            },
            jsonp: "jsoncallback"
        });

        function onRouteCalculated(data) {
            if (data.response) {
                var position = data.response.route[0].waypoint[0].mappedPosition;
                var coordinate = new nokia.maps.map.StandardMarker([position.latitude, position.longitude]);
                var tempContainer = new nokia.maps.map.Container();
                tempContainer.objects.add(coordinate);
                map.zoomTo(multiMapContainer.getBoundingBox().merge(tempContainer.getBoundingBox()), false);
            }
        }
    }
```

I debugged through it in Chrome and I can see that zoomTo does actually zoom to the proper bounding box, but then right after I hit the 'continue' button it jumps back to the highest zoom level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently came across a similar issue. The basic issue was that the containing `<DIV>` for the `map` was itself being initialized during the map initialization. My problem was compounded because `map.zoomTo()` doesn't work during map initialization anyway (since 2.5.3 map loading is always asynchronous)

The crux of the issue was that I was trying to use `zoomTo()` on a 0x0 pixel map since the `<DIV>` wasn't displayed yet - hence I ended up with a `zoomLevel` zero map.

The solution is to add listeners to the map as shown:

```
map.addListener("displayready", function () {
    if(bbox){map.zoomTo(bbox, false);}
});
map.addListener("resize", function () {
    if(bbox){map.zoomTo(bbox, false);}
});
```

And set up the `bbox` parameter as each `coordinate` is received as shown:

```
function onCoordinateReceived(coordinate){
   if(bbox){
           bbox = nokia.maps.geo.BoundingBox.coverAll([
           bbox.topLeft, bbox.bottomRight, coordinate]);
   } else {
           bbox = nokia.maps.geo.BoundingBox.coverAll([coordinate]);
   }
   map.zoomTo(bbox, false);
}
```

So that:

- If the  `map` is already intialized and displayed the `zoomTo()` in the  `onCoordinateReceived()` will fire
- If the  `map` completes intialization after  `onCoordinateReceived()`, the `zoomTo()` in the  `displayready` listener will fire.
- If the  `<DIV>` update occurs last, the `zoomTo()` in the  `resize` listener will fire, which will alter from a zoomed Out map to the "*right*" zoom level.

Comment: Ah fantastic, this is just what I needed. I had no idea about the existence of the displayready and didn't realize that my container was resizing itself.